# Convert ASCII string encoded array into string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Input:**

```
'0x0 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f 0x8E 0x21'
```

**Output:**

```
Hello!
```

**Current Solution:**

```
    s = []
    birary_data = '0x0 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f 0x8E 0x21'.replace(' ', '').split('0x')
    for c in birary_data:
        if len(c) > 1:
            s.append(bytes.fromhex(c).decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
    print("".join(s))
```

**Need help with:**

Could anyone suggest a more elegant solution, please?

Comment: Why do you think your solution is not elegant ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, it feels like I'm doing extra and unnecessary steps. However, there could a very simple solution, like birary_data.decode('hex')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
data = '0x0 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f 0x8E 0x21'
string = "".join([chr(int(item, 16)) for item in data.split()])
print(string)
```

**Output:**

```
Hello!
```

Comment: I always forget that int can take a base, this is a good solution

Comment: Doesn't this have a leading null byte and something else before the last char?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below one
Here in the code i am first splitting the hex according to white-space and then iterating and joining the character i get.

```
a = '0x0 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f 0x8E 0x21'
print(''.join(chr(int(i, 16)) for i in a.split()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to remove 3 characters (or less) length substrings, `0x` and white spaces. `bytes.fromhex` can handle a string like `'48656c6c6f8E21'`

```
binary_data = '0X0 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f 0x8E 0x21'
binary_data = re.sub(r'\b\w{3}\b|\s?0x', '', binary_data)
print(bytes.fromhex(binary_data).decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Comment: why not change your pattern to `r'\b\w{3}\b|\s?0x'` to get `'48656c6c6f8E21'` directly?

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `bytes.fromhex()` is very nearly all we need. There are however two problems we need to get around:

- The null byte at the front
- The invalid char in position 6 (`0x8E`)

```py
import re

data = '0x0 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f 0x8E 0x21'

string = bytes.fromhex(re.sub('0x(0 )?', '', data)).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

The regex will take care of both stripping the null byte and formatting the string correctly for `bytes.fromhex()`. The `ignore` in the decode will skip the bad byte.

Answer (score 0):

```py
birary_data = '0x0 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f 0x8E 0x21'.replace('0x', '').split()
print(bytearray.fromhex(''.join(c for c in birary_data if len(c) > 1)).decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Output:

```
Hello!
```